# Hair Dynamics does not collide with its own mesh

Tags: hair

My issue is as topic states. **The hairdynamics of my mesh goes right through the mesh itself, the hair does not collide.**

I have been searching around the internet and looked up several posts here on Blender Stack Exchange, and it seems that no one have found a sollution yet, or atleast not shared it, as in explained it in a detailed way. There is alot discussions about it, but no sollutions from what I can see. I found one like old workaround for a old blender version, but I am using 2.79 and it would make sense if there was a more simple way to achieve this.

So my question is simply, how can I make the  hair collide with its own mesh? so it does not go through it?

This might not be the best example, but you can see here in the GIF that the hair goes straight through the mesh it is attatched to.

Here is a GIF showing the issue (I could not upload it trough the image function here, it did not let me, trust me I tried, I believe it might be too big file)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqMf0.jpg